# How can I stop to restart the kernel with PyRoot?

Tags: anaconda, kernel, spyder, pyroot

I'm new to Pyroot and I don't know how to fix a little problem. I'm using Pyroot on Spyder 5.1 (Anaconda) because ROOT isn't compatible for now with macOS Monterey. I installed Root 6.24/08 on Spyder, I tried a simple program like the one in the photo  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Y5nm.png)  but I didn't see any plot and the terminal says "restarting kernel ...". I tried to do only "import ROOT" and nothing else and run the program but the error is the same. I also tried to add some numbers to print but the error is the same, only if I remove "import ROOT" I can print the numbers. What can I do? thank you!

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) I don't understand how you installed Root, but the error you mention suggests you have incompatibility issues between the package you downloaded and Spyder. To solve them, I suggest that you follow the instructions mentioned in this [FAQ](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/5/faq.html#using-packages-installer) in our docs, and use the following command to install Root: `conda install -c conda-forge pyroot`.

Comment: I installed pyroot with the command conda install root. Now I check if I have some possible incompatibility issues.